# How can I make all fields required unless specified otherwise in Rails forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many forms. All of a fields required except one.
Any way mark them required except one as optional?

Comment: not satisfied with the proposed solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think there is a way to do this other than putting `required: true` for each field

Or Put a validation in your model for each column

```
validates :order, presence: true
```

Comment: `presence: true` only works if you're using Simpleform, has no effect on the regular `form_for` method

Comment: Don't think @Iceman `presence: true` is in your `ActiveRecord` model it doesn't matter if it is `form_for` or `form_tag`

Comment: I was not talking about `form_for` or `form_tag`, I said that there is no UI difference in having `presence: true` in your model unless you're using SimpleForm, which puts an asterisk (*) next to the required fields when the form is generated.

Answer (score -2):

There is no other built in way. You could write a wrapper that adds required: true to all fields by default. 
It is however, easiest to just put all params in the model and validate by

```
presence: true
```

and add HTML to the fields

```
required: true
```

Can you please let us know whether the normal validation by model is sufficient for your purposes? There is no need to add extra HTML attributes.

In simple_form gem you can set attributes to be required by default.

```
config.required_by_default = true
```

Then you can overwrite by using

, `required: false`

you could try to write such a line yourself if you do not use the SimpelForm gem.

If not sufficient please edit your question by stating what exactly you need. According to my knowledge there is only validation in rails as built in function.

Comment: `presence: true` only works if you're using Simpleform, has no effect on the regular `form_for` method